# Unable to implement infinityscoll v4 with dynamic gallery php masonry

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, infinite-scroll

I am trying to implement infinite scrolling with my images. All of my images are in a folder called img (50 images) I am displaying 10 images per page. When I am trying to append the images via infinite scrolling I am unable to do that. I am running into an error. Can anyone suggest me how to implement infinite scrolling plugin on this. Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dynamic Image Gallery with Infinite Scrolling and Masonry</title>
    <style>
        .gallery {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.gallery-item {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 10px;
}

.gallery-item img {
    width: 100%;
}

.pagination {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .gallery-item {
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .gallery-item {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="gallery">
        <?php
        // Retrieve all the available image names from a directory and save them into an array
        $dir = "img/";
        $images = glob($dir."*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);

        // Calculate the total number of pages based on the number of images and the number of images per page
        $images_per_page = 10;
        $total_pages = ceil(count($images) / $images_per_page);

        // Retrieve the current page number from the URL query string or set it to 1 if it's not present
        $current_page = isset($_GET["page"]) ? $_GET["page"] : 1;

        // Calculate the starting index and ending index of images to display based on the current page number and the number of images per page
        $start_index = ($current_page - 1) * $images_per_page;
        $end_index = $start_index + $images_per_page;

        // Generate HTML code for each image in the directory and display it on the webpage
        for ($i = $start_index; $i < $end_index && $i < count($images); $i++) {
            echo '<div class="gallery-item">';
            echo '<a href="'.$images[$i].'" data-lightbox="gallery">';
            echo '<img src="img/placeholder.jpg" data-src="'.$images[$i].'" alt="Gallery Image">';
            echo '</a>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
        ?>
    </div>

    <?php if ($current_page < $total_pages): ?>
    <div class="pagination">
        <a href="?page=<?php echo $current_page + 1; ?>"></a>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-infinitescroll/4.0.1/infinite-scroll.pkgd.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/4.2.2/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vanilla-lazyload/17.3.0/lazyload.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lazyLoadInstance = new LazyLoad({
        elements_selector: ".gallery img",
        threshold: 500,
        callback_loaded: function(element) {
            var masonryInstance = $(".gallery").data("masonry");
            masonryInstance.layout();
        }
    });

    var $container = $(".gallery");
    $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: ".gallery-item",
            columnWidth: ".gallery-item",
            percentPosition: true,
        });
    });

    $(".gallery").infinitescroll({
        navSelector: ".pagination",
        nextSelector: ".pagination a:first",
        itemSelector: ".gallery-item",
        loading: {
            finishedMsg: "No more images to load.",
            img: "https://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif"
        },
        path: function() {
            var nextPage = this.pageNumber + 1;
            if (nextPage <= <?php echo $total_pages; ?>) {
                return "index.php?page=" + nextPage;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }, function(newElements) {
        $(newElements).imagesLoaded(function() {
            $container.masonry("appended", $(newElements));
            lazyLoadInstance.update();
        });
    });
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

i have tried the documentation of infinitescroll

```
let elem = document.querySelector('.container');let infScroll = new InfiniteScroll( elem, {// optionspath: function() {var nextPage = this.pageNumber + 1;if (nextPage <= <?php echo $total_pages; ?>) {return "index.php?page=" + nextPage;} else {return null;}},append: '.gallery-item',history: false,});
```

this doesn't worked . i couldnot understand how to pass the path . as i am able to access via ' `index.php?page=3` ' . any suggestion would be helpful.